# string permutation. storing in an array returns same set of permutations?

Tags: python

**UPDATED:see below line**
Unless I am missing something?

```
from array import array

def string_permute(ar, lo, hi, result):
    if lo == hi:
        # print ar # this gives correct permutated output, howcome result isn't able to store that?
        result.append(ar)
    else:
        for index in xrange(lo, hi+1):
            ar[index], ar[lo] = ar[lo], ar[index]
            string_permute(ar, lo+1, hi, result)
            ar[index], ar[lo] = ar[lo], ar[index]
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = array('c', '1234')
    result = []
    string_permute(f, 0, len(f)-1, result)
    print result
```

outputs:

```
[array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234'), array('c', '1234')]
```

expected output:

```
array('c', '1234') array('c', '1243') array('c', '1324') array('c', '1342') array('c', '1432') array('c', '1423') array('c', '2134') array('c', '2143') array('c', '2314') array('c', '2341') array('c', '2431') array('c', '2413') array('c', '3214') array('c', '3241') array('c', '3124') array('c', '3142') array('c', '3412') array('c', '3421') array('c', '4231') array('c', '4213') array('c', '4321') array('c', '4312') array('c', '4132') array('c', '4123')
```

I tried passing in `result = result or []` and then doing a

```
result += string_permute(ar, lo+1, hi, result)
return result #at the end of loop
```

but that too is counter productive and outputs the same. I don't know why.
it is not because of this `array` I also tried it solely with a list.

---

As mentioned in one of the answers below, I used a list instead.

```
def string_permute(ar, lo, hi, result):
    if lo == hi:
        result.append(ar[:])  #why does this work and result.append(ar) doesn't?
        print ar
    else:
        for index in xrange(lo, hi+1):
            ar[index], ar[lo] = ar[lo], ar[index]
            string_permute(ar, lo+1, hi, result)
            ar[index], ar[lo] = ar[lo], ar[index]
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = array('c', '1234').tolist()  #just made it into a list
    result = []
    string_permute(f, 0, len(f)-1, result)
    print result
```

**Q:** why does this work and `result.append(ar)` doesn't?

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: @LutzHorn a list of following:

array('c', '1234')
array('c', '1243')
array('c', '1324')
array('c', '1342')
array('c', '1432')
array('c', '1423')
array('c', '2134')
array('c', '2143')
array('c', '2314')
array('c', '2341')
array('c', '2431')
array('c', '2413')
array('c', '3214')
array('c', '3241')
array('c', '3124')
array('c', '3142')
array('c', '3412')
array('c', '3421')
array('c', '4231')
array('c', '4213')
array('c', '4321')
array('c', '4312')
array('c', '4132')
array('c', '4123')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying `ar` inplace, so you end up with `result` containing multiple copies of same object. Changing `result.append(ar)` to `result.append(ar[:])` in `string_permute` solves the problem.

Comment: what if i use a list instead? would that affect?

Comment: I added like you said. it works. so i added the question too.

Answer (score 3):

You did not make a copy for array object. So therefore, each time you try to modify the array, it changes for every function call.

When you do recursive call each time, make a copy for array object.

```
import copy

string_permute(copy.copy(ar), lo+1, hi, result)
```

Comment: Or, use a list, and pass `ar[:]` into the recursion.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I add this question. why ar doesn't work and ar[:] works? What's the difference?

Comment: Because `[:]` makes a copy.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so when I `print ar` and do `result.append(ar[:])` why does `print ar` gives the correct answer? Is it that through recursion ar references the original list?